# Send UDP packets through no IP assigned bridge interface in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, udp, bridge, sendto

I have two network interfaces (e.g. eth0 and eth1) configured as two ends of a bridge in Ubuntu Linux 14.04. They are not assigned with any IP addresses. eth0 is physically connected to a subnet. I want to send UDP packets through eth0 to a subnet connected machine. I create a UDP socket and check that it can successfully bind to eth0 (i.e. setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, eth0, strlen(eth0)), and executing sendto() reports success as well. However, the designated target machine cannot receive anything from eth0!!

Is there any Ubuntu tools/commands to trace where the UDP packets go (actually, I did try to use Wireshark. But, Wireshark cannot detect any network interface to capture!)?

And, is there any workarounds, under the situation that eth0 and eth1 must be set as a interconnected bridge with no IP addresses, to make use of eth0 to send UDP packets to other machine with designated IP address and port?

Comment: What should go in the "sender IP" field in the header of the outgoing packet?  The Linux TCP/IP stack isn't being given all the information needed to create a packet, so you'll probably have to write the headers yourself and use a raw socket to transmit.

Comment: Ben, would you advise me with references and codes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can I hijack the created socket to fill in fake sender IP info?

Comment: Perhaps search for `IP_HDRINCL example` in your favorite search engine?